# Removing double quotes from a whole column in a table with multiple items in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column in a table where some list of items (cuisine types) are strings with quotations and some without quotations. I want to remove all the double quotation marks in the whole column so there are no quotation marks.

ex.

```
**Cuisine Type**

"Pizza","Italian"
"Pizza","Italian"
"Pizza","Italian"
"Pizza","Italian"
American, Italian, Pizza
Bowls, Breakfast, Burritos, Chicken, Coffee and Tea, Dessert, Dinner
Bowls, Breakfast, Burritos, Chicken, Coffee and Tea, Dessert, Dinner
Bowls, Breakfast, Burritos, Chicken, Coffee and Tea, Dessert, Dinner
Bowls, Breakfast, Burritos, Chicken, Coffee and Tea, Dessert, Dinner
```

I have looked at trim method but it takes in a specific work ex.

```
select trim(both '"' from ___)
```

Is there a way of filtering out all the double quotation marks in the column?

Comment: It is never a good idea to store multiple values as csv in a column

Answer (score 0):

How about the [replace](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/replace-function.php) function:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE (Cuisine Type, '"', '') from <table_name>;
```